# Creating a versatile data class in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

I'm hoping you good folks can help with a project I'm working on. Essentially, I am trying to create a class that will take as an input a CSV file, examine the file for the number of columns of data, and store that data in key, value pairs in a dictionary. The code I have up to this point is below:

```
import csv

class DataStandard():
'''class to store and examine columnar data saved as a csv file'''

def __init__(self, file_name):
self.file_name = file_name

self.full_data_set = {}

with open(self.file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # get labels of each column in list format
    self.col_labels = next(reader)

    # find the number of columns of data in the file
    self.number_of_cols = len(self.col_labels)

    # initialize lists to store data using column label as key
    for label in self.col_labels:
        self.full_data_set[label] = []
```

The piece I am having a hard time with is once the dictionary (full_data_set) is created I'm not sure how to loop through the remainder of the CSV file and store the data in the respective values for each key (column). Everything I have tried until now hasn't worked because of how I have to loop through the csv.reader object.
I hope this question makes sense, but please feel free to ask any clarifying questions. Also, if you think of an approach that may work in a better more pythonic way I would appreciate the input. This is one of my first self-guided projects on class, so the subject is fairly new to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `for row in reader:`

Comment: you could use `zip(self.col_labels, row)` to create pairs  `(key,value)` but if you have more rows then you should rather create `list of dictionares`.

Comment: The `csv` module has a `DictReader` class.

Answer (score 0):

To read rows you can use `for row in reader`

```
data = []

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    headers = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        d = dict(zip(headers, row))
        #print(d)
        data.append(d)

print('data:', data)
```

As said @PM2Ring `csv` has `DictReader`

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print('data:', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you ideas towards a solution. It is assumed that the labels are only on row 1, and the rest is data, and then the row length becomes 0 when there is no data:

```
import csv

class DataStandard():
'''class to store and examine columnar data saved as a csv file'''

def __init__(self, file_name):
self.file_name = file_name

self.full_data_set = {}

#modify method to the following:

with open(self.file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        if row = 0:

            # get labels of each column in list format
            self.col_labels = next(reader)

            # find the number of columns of data in the file
            self.number_of_cols = len(self.col_labels)

            # initialize lists to store data using column label as key
            for label in self.col_labels:
                self.full_data_set[label] = []

        else:
            if len(row) != 0:
                for i in range(self.number_of_cols):
                    label = self.col_labels[i]
                    self.full_data_set[label] = next(reader)
```

...My one concern is that while the 'with open(...)' is valid, some levels of indentation can be ignored, from my experience. In that case, to reduce the number of indentations, I would just separate 'row=0' and 'row!=0' operations into different instances of 'with open(...)' i.e. do row 1, close, open again, do row 2.